# How to include a php file with in WordPress header file

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi there I seem to have run into an issue that I'm not quite sure about. I have a just developed a new WordPress theme for my personal website and I have some include files in the header which aren't being added.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?php language_attributes(); ?>">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/favicon.ico" />

  <title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>

  <!-- Google Analytics Tracking-->
  <?php include_once("/inc/google-analytics-tracking.php") ?>

  <!-- Drip Tracking -->
  <?php include_once("/inc/drip-tracking.php") ?>

  <!-- Hotjar Tracking -->
  <?php include_once("/inc/hotjar-tracking.php") ?>

  <!-- ConvertFlow Tracking -->
  <?php include_once("/inc/convertflow-tracking.php") ?>

  <!-- Share This -->
  <?php include_once("/inc/share-this.php") ?>

  <?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>
```

You can see my site here: https://www.elliottdavidson.com/. I'm not sure why the includes arent working? If anyone could shed any light on this it would be great.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php anything from that? Could be a path issue.

Comment: I take it you left the question. Well, you've an answer below, see that. If it doesn't resolve the question, well............ there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/inc/` - it's an absolute path, if you want to use relative paths you have to write this string as `inc/` because `/` means "root" directory of the linux file system.

Comment: *"because / means "root" directory of the linux file system"* - Sure, but how are we to know which OS it's running under? He could be using this under Windows. So that part should have been a comment under your answer, or as an added "NOTE:...".

Comment: @Fred-ii- actually he posted an url to his site, I see that he use Linux OS with Apache.

Comment: OK. Well, the OP seems to either have left the question or is unresponsive. I asked the guy to check for errors in a comment, so that tells me that it's one or the other. He's going to have to come back and say/do something.

Comment: @Fred-ii- in the same time slashes in PHP work for Windows too, so his relative path will work everywhere. And only in Linux OS first shash means root directory.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, in the end, the files don't want to be added into the header.php file but into the functions.php file like so:

```
// Google Analytics Tracking
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/google-analytics.php';
```